# Как в Swift получить изображение из интернета в переменную?

Tags: swift, изображения

Имеется константа типа URL с адресом к рандомной картинке, например:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/72c0b2_85751edb34ad4eb888e3091a1c893553~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_924,h_500,al_c,q_90/72c0b2_85751edb34ad4eb888e3091a1c893553~mv2.jpg")
```

Далее я делаю GET запрос для получения этой картинки:

```
 var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
     //Что-то тут
 }
```

и он успешно происходит, вероятно где-то в data хранится картинка. Как мне её получить в переменную, и правильно ли я понимаю что переменная должна быть типа UIImage? В дальнейшем планируется полученную картинку сохранять на диск и/или отправлять в качестве данных в POST запросах.

PS по реально используемой ссылке всегда имеется изображение в формате jpeg, в этом можно быть уверенным и проверять это не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы можете создать переменную типа UIImage из полученных данных:

let image = UIImage(data: data)

- init(data:) Initializes and returns the image object with the specified data.

Comment: Тестовый код выдаёт множество ошибок:
let url = URL(string: "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/72c0b2_85751edb34ad4eb888e3091a1c893553~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_924,h_500,al_c,q_90/72c0b2_85751edb34ad4eb888e3091a1c893553~mv2.jpg")

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
task.resume()
Видимо проблема преобразования типов. Если текстовый ответ сервера нужно извлекать конструкций String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self) то изображение то же возможно нужно как-то декодировать?

Comment: Нет, у вас data Optional, просто оберните в проверку: if let data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            }

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает, (хоть пока и не совсем понимаю почему) :)

Comment: data в этом случае это набор двоичных данных, которые преобразуются в картинку. При этом data может не вернуться (при ошибке и т.д.), т.е. значения не будет, будет nil (отсутствие значения), т.е. тип данных у data это Data? (Optional Data). Поэтому мы делаем проверку if let data {} (раньше бы писали if let data = data {}, но новый Swift позволяет сократить выражение), тем самым проверяя, что в data есть значение и превращая тип data из Data? в просто Data, т.к. UIImage принимает на вход не опциональный тип Data. Как-то так.